# write a while loop using promises using return values within the next promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, bluebird, request-promise

I have read all the questions on SO about this subject but I'm still stuck because the `condition` function in `promiseWhile` does not take a parameter.

My use case is the following. I am trying to query some information for some date (`start_date`). I do not know whether there is info for `start_date` in my db so I want to check for that. If there is no data, I want to query the day before and keep doing that until there is data.
(I know the `promise while loop` is not the best way to do that but I want to learn how to do it nonetheless)

Here is my code so far

```js
let start_date = DateTime.fromFormat(req.body.date, "yyyy-MM-dd");
let date_promise = (the_date) => {
    let the_req = {
        date: the_date
    };
    return db.query(the_req);
};

let promiseWhile = Promise.method(function (condition, action) {
    if (!condition()) return;
    return action().then(promiseWhile.bind(null, condition, action));
});

promiseWhile(
    (body) => {return body.rows.length > 0},
    () => {
        start_date = start_date.minus(luxon.Duration.fromObject({days: 1}))
        return date_promise(start_date);
    },
).then((result) => {
    // start_date ... 
    // do something with the date I've obtained
});
```

`date_promise` return a promise.

In my `promiseWhile` condition I am trying to test that `body.rows` contains something with `body` being the parameter of the `.then` function after the result of `date_promise` resolves. (`date_promise(some_date).then((body) => {...})`).

I am not sure how to proceed from there. Any help welcome.

Comment: First 2 problems I see is a) in your condition you say the function gets a `body` parameter, yet in `promiseWhile` you call the `condition` function with no parameters. b) on `action().then(promiseWhile(...))` you got the wrong syntax. Try changing it to `action().then(() => promiseWhile(...))`

Comment: Thks for taking the time. Yes a) exactly my issue. How do you write a `condition` function that takes a parameter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promise.method is an older version of [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). With that in mind and a few syntax corrections, your code would look like this:

```
let start_date = DateTime.fromFormat(req.body.date, "yyyy-MM-dd");

let date_promise = (the_date) => {
    let the_req = {
        date: the_date
    };
    return db.query(the_req);
};

const myAction = date => () => date_promise(date);

let promiseWhile = async function (condition, action) {
    const queryResults = await action();
    if (!condition(queryResults)) {
      start_date = start_date.minus(luxon.Duration.fromObject({days: 1}));
      return promiseWhile(condition, myAction(start_date));
    } else {
      return queryResults;
    }
};

promiseWhile(
    body => body.rows.length > 0,
    () => {
        return myAction(start_date);
    },
).then(result => { // The result you'll get here is queryResults.
    // start_date ... 
    // do something with the date I've obtained
});
```

Comment: How do I get `body` (within `promiseWhile`) to be the result of the `date_promise().then(..)` ?

Comment: I editted the question to recall promiseWhile with a new date every time. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: trying now thank you for your time. Why have you created a `currentDate` variable instead of using `start_date` directly ? Also `myAction` is exactly `date_promise` isn't it ? Any reason why you created a new function ?

Comment: OK it works. Great. Only things I modified was 1. I did not use the `currentDate` variable and 2. `myAction` shoudl return a function so I used `const myAction = (date) => {
        return () => date_promise(date);
    };`

Comment: Could you modify your answer to incorporate those and I'll validate. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: also the first call of promiseWhile should not modify `start_date`

Comment: I modified my answer according to your comments. Please check it now.